# Groupby Multi-Column Sort based on hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I am trying to sort outcome of a groupby by the hierarchy / order of the columns.

Example of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A1','A1'],
                   'B':['B2','B1','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2'],
                   'C':['C1','C3','C1','C3','C2','C2','C1','C3'],
                   'V':[100,240,110,120,50,60,40,40]})
```

Followed by the groupby operation:

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).agg({'V':'sum'}).sort_values(by=['A','V','B','V'],ascending=[False,False,False,False])
```

Output:

```
            V
A   B   C   
A2  B1  C3  120
    B2  C2  60
    B1  C2  50
A1  B1  C3  240
    B2  C1  140
    B1  C1  110
    B2  C3  40
```

What I want however is A1 should be sorted first based on it's own total value (irrespective of B & C values), followed by B based on it's own total.

So the output should look something like this:

```
            V
A   B   C   
A1  B1  C3  240
    B1  C1  110
    B2  C1  140
    B2  C3  40
A2  B1  C3  120
    B1  C2  50
    B2  C2  60
```

Let me know if I could explain it well.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A1','A1'],
                   'B':['B2','B1','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2'],
                   'C':['C1','C3','C1','C3','C2','C2','C1','C3'],
                   'V':[100,240,110,120,50,60,40,40]})




aa = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).sum()
print(aa)


"""
            V
A  B  C      
A1 B1 C1  110
      C3  240
   B2 C1  140
      C3   40
A2 B1 C2   50
      C3  120
   B2 C2   60

"""


t1= (
    df.groupby(['A','B','C']).sum().sort_values(['V','C'],ascending=False)
    .sort_index(level=[0,1],sort_remaining = False)
    )

print(t1)

"""
            V
A  B  C      
A1 B1 C3  240
      C1  110
   B2 C1  140
      C3   40
A2 B1 C3  120
      C2   50
   B2 C2   60

"""
```

Comment: I took that as an answer as it did what I wanted to do in this scenario. But I still wanted to explore how I can control that sorting. e.g. if you have multiple functions - sum, count etc., I really can't chose my preference. Also, if I want C to be sorted within the group (A,B) by V, I can't do that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to sort by `A`, `B` and `V` column in the same time

```py
out = (df.groupby(['A','B','C']).agg({'V':'sum'})
       .sort_values(by=['A','B','V'], ascending=[True,True,False]))
```

```
print(out)

            V
A  B  C
A1 B1 C3  240
      C1  110
   B2 C1  140
      C3   40
A2 B1 C3  120
      C2   50
   B2 C2   60
```

Comment: Not really. I want A & B to be sorted not by it's own alphabetical order but by it's group-by total value.